# Doble cabecera. Separar cabecera

Tags: r

Supongamos que quiero hacer una tabla con datos de Starwars:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat1 <- starwars[,c("species","gender","homeworld","eye_color")]

pivot_wider(dat1, names_from = c(gender,species), values_from = eye_color,
            values_fn = function(x) paste(x, collapse=","))
```

La cabecera de la tabla une gender y species, quedando algo como esto:

```
homeworld  masculine_Human masculine_Droid feminine_Human
```

¿Se puede hacer de forma que ponga una doble cabecera de este estilo?:

```
                     masculine                  feminine    
homeworld     Human  Droid  Wookiee     Human  Droid  Wookiee
```

Comment: No, los data.frame o tibbles no manejan el concepto de cabecera tal como lo podrías manejar en un Excel, estos objetos son básicamente tablas, dónde solo hay filas y columnas. Sin embargo, hay paquetes para presentar estos datos de la forma que estás queriendo, pero es solo presentación, el datos seguiría siendo el mismo.

Comment: ¿Y que paquete recomiendas para representar los datos con doble cabecera?

Comment: Lo que más ceo que se usa, es `kable`  y  `kableExtra` pero hay varios paquetes más: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/table-other.html

Comment: Con `kable` hay ejemplos de como implementar algo parecido: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#Add_header_rows_to_group_columns

Comment: kable tiene muy buena pinta. Gracias!